# array looping issue 

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array

```
Array(
Array
(
    [Segment] => Array
        (
            [id] => 738
    )
),
Array
(
    [Segment] => Array
        (
            [0] => array([id] => 740),
            [1] => array([id] => 750)
    )
)
)
```

how can i loop the array. The second value need inner loop.

i need the output as

first loop as id->738

second loop as id->740, id->750

Regards,
Nisanth

Comment: The array format is a bit weird. Who generates it?

Comment: actually it is returned from an API

Comment: Ok. So, have you tried plain old `foreach`?

Comment: i can check the count and write if/else condition to loop inner loops. But im searching a simple solution if we change the array structure

Comment: if the structure is changed - you need to change your correspondent code.

Comment: If its possible to change the array structure, then change the structure of the first case to `[0] -> array([id] => 738)` this would be the proper solution...

Comment: @loler: current structure is just inconsistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
foreach($array as $a) {
    foreach($a as $segment => $array) {
        if(isset($array['id'])) {
           echo $array['id']; //if there is an `id` index echo it
        } else {
           foreach($array as $k => $v) { //or else.. start looping again
               echo $v['id'];
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @gautamdharmapuri, Haven't tested but it should. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to collect all the id values.

Try:

```
$ids = array();
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v, $k) use (&$ids) {
  $ids[] = $v;
});
var_dump($ids);
```